# Can I set a property on an object that is only declared on the instance type, when I don't know the type?

Tags: reflection, object, types, instance, propertyinfo

Let me explain. I have a List into which I am adding various ASP.NET controls.
I then wish to loop through the list and set a CssClass, however not every Control supports the property CssClass.

What I would like to do is test if the underlying instance type supports the CssClass property and set it, but I'm not sure how to do the conversion prior to setting the property since I don't know the type of each Control object.

I know that I can use typeof or x.GetType(), but I'm not sure how to use these to convert the controls back to the instance type in order to test for and then set the property.

---

Actually I seem to have solved this, so I thought that I would post the code here for others.

```
foreach (Control c in controlList) {
    PropertyInfo pi = c.GetType().GetProperty("CssClass");
    if (pi != null) pi.SetValue(c, "desired_css_class", null);
}
```

I hope that this helps someone else as I has taken me hours to research these 2 lines of code.

Cheers

Steve

Comment: Out of curiosity - what took so long to find the answer?

Comment: Good work. post it as an answer steve.

Comment: What took so long was not quite knowing where to start and what to search for.
I spent a long time trying to find a way to cast the object back to its instance type, but I could not find how to declare the variable that would hold the cast type since I didn't know it's type. 
Maybe someone could tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow Preet's advice I have also posted this as an answer.

```
foreach (Control c in controlList) {
    PropertyInfo pi = c.GetType().GetProperty("CssClass");
    if (pi != null) pi.SetValue(c, "desired_css_class", null);
}
```

I hope that this helps someone in the future (probably me when I google it again).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to think about re-designing these classes making them implement an interface `ICssControl` or something along the lines which provides the CssClass property.

```
interface ICssControl
```

{
  string CssClass { get; set;}
 }

You can then implement your logic as:

```
string desiredCssClass = "desired_css_class";
foreach (var control in controlList)
{
    var cssObj = control as ICssControl;
    if (cssObj != null)
        cssObj.CssClass = desiredCssClass;
}
```

This gets you away from needing to use reflection at all and should make for easier refactoring later on.

**Edit**

On re-reading you question, maybe you already have this interface and are asking how to cast it back to that interface?